# Is there a way to use iconv() in R to correctly encode the entire dataframe?

Tags: r

I'm working with a new dataset, but after importing it, it shows an incorrect encoding. All the "ã" show up as  something else.

I found a way to fix a column with iconv(), but is there a simple way to use it for all 389 columns?

`md2016 <- read_delim("~microdados_2016", ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)`

```
md2016$v1 <- iconv(md2016$v1, to = "UTF-8"
```

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that in R, UTF-8 and data frames do not mix on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lapply`:

```
md2016new <- lapply(md2016, iconv, to = "UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 3):

A tidyverse-solution:

```
df<-df %>%
      mutate_if(is.character, 
                function(col) iconv(col, to="UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load data straight into a dataframe and convert it in one step.
You will need 'readr' (standalone or part of 'tidyverse')

First guess what encoding the input data is

```
readr::guess_encoding("path/to/file.csv")
```

Note the result, for me it was

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  encoding   confidence
  <chr>           <dbl>
1 ISO-8859-1       0.27
2 ISO-8859-2       0.21
```

Then use readr with some arguments including the input encoding value found above

```
data <- read_csv("path/to/file.csv", 
                        locale = locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-2",
                        asciify = TRUE))
```