# Issue with Non-ASCII Characters in R

Tags: r, text, character-encoding, special-characters

I am loading data in R with free-text fields that have a variety of non-ASCII/double byte characters. Depending on the function I use to load the data or the format in which the data is stored (`.csv` or `.xlsx`), the characters appear differently.

Specifically, if I use `read.csv` with a `.csv` file or `read_excel` with a `.xlsx` file the characters appears something like: `Orientaciï¿½n mï¿½s`.

Meanwhile, if I use `read_csv` with a `.csv` file they appear like this: `Orientaci�n m�s`

Is there file format/data load combination to fix this issue? Or is there some way to decode the data in either format once it is already loaded? I have explored a variety of methods including changing the encoding arguments where applicable and the `decoder` package, but I can't get anything to work.

Thoughts?

EDIT: Per comments below I have tried the following:

```
readr::guess_encoding("file with issue.csv")
    # A tibble: 2 x 2
  encoding   confidence
  <chr>           <dbl>
1 UTF-8            1   
2 ISO-8859-1       0.52

readr::guess_encoding("file without issue.csv")
guess_encoding("Goal_Details.csv")
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  encoding     confidence
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 UTF-8              1   
2 windows-1252       0.51

iconv(x,"ISO-8859-1","windows-1252")
```

`x` Corresponds to the string/field with the issue, but it still doesn't fix the problem.

Thoughts?

Comment: I usually find it easier to convert the files to a consistent encoding (utf8, e.g., with the `iconv` command) before loading them into R.

Comment: The encoding is in most cases independent from the file format. For text-based files you should prefer the `readr` functions over the base R functions as they handle encoding issues much better. What does `readr::guess_encoding` report for your csv?

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd see edits above.

Comment: @AEF see edits above.

Comment: I had the same issue and could fix it with readr, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890490/is-there-a-way-to-use-iconv-in-r-to-correctly-encode-the-entire-dataframe/63666856#63666856)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, the answer is that the ’�’ already is decoded. At some point the original characters were not decoded, so windows defaults to basically saying “I don’t know what this is”, and it does that for any non-ASCII character.

For example, there’s no distinguishing between á and ¿ once reaching this point. There are crosswalks available for these types of characters, but they wouldn’t work here as replacement would need to be at the language level, which is an entirely different issue.

Essentially, one would either have to replace or remove the ’�’ and run a spell checker in multiple languages.